# How to add creamy taste and consistency to pasta dish with cheese?

Tags: cheese, pasta

I enjoy a plate of pasta every now and then, so yesterday, I made a large pot of pasta combining penne noodles, shrimp, scallops, garden-fresh zuccini squash, cheese, and seasoning.

Everything turned out great, but one thing seemed missing to me.  Whenever I have a dish of pasta with cheese in a restaurant, the cheese sauce usually has a very rich, creamy taste and consistency that I found missing in the dish that I prepared.

How can I add a rich, creamy taste and consistency to pasta dishes?

Answer (score 5):

This is going to sound a little facetious, but a good way to add creaminess is... Add cream.

If you want something a little lighter, you can use a few egg yolks, tempered and whisked with hot pasta water and mixed through the pasta with the rest of the ingredients. This, along with plenty of parmesan, is the basic method for carbonara.

Comment: This is going to sound a bit facetious, but I'm a novice at cooking and I don't know exactly what sort of cream you refer to.

Comment: I think the American term is heavy cream. Pour it in with the rest of your ingredients, then scoop the pasta into the pan and mix through. Allow some of the pasta water to get in there too, which will help create a nice sauce.

Comment: @RiceFlourCookies - continuing all the facetiousness, regular dairy cream should work just fine - the stuff sold in stores next to milk, rich with milk solids and butterfat, available just about everywhere, labeled as heavy or light based on percent butterfat, sometimes called whipping cream (err, *not* "whipped", that's different).  Of course, if you wanted to look for more exotic creams - like coconut cream or nut cream or whatever - those would probably also serve the intended purpose.